# Least Square by Lagragian mutipliers with complex variables

Tags: optimization, complex-numbers, lagrange-multiplier, least-squares

First let me put some context to my question.
 It is not hard to find a derivation of optimal solution of

\begin{eqnarray}
     \text{Minimize } & \phi = \frac{1}{2}\left\|Ax - y\right\|^{2}_{2} \nonumber
  \end{eqnarray}
in least square sense ($x=(A^{T}A)^{-1}A^{T}y$).

We also can do it by Lagrange multiplier:

\begin{eqnarray}
     \text{Minimize }   & x^{T}x \nonumber\\
     \text{Subject to } & Ax = y \nonumber
  \end{eqnarray}
  Introduce Lagrange multipliers: $L(x,\lambda) = x^{T}x + \lambda^{T}(Ax-y)$

Optimality conditions are 
  \begin{eqnarray}
    \nabla_{x}L &=& 2x + A^{T}\lambda = 0, \\
    \nabla_{\lambda}L &=& Ax-y = 0.
  \end{eqnarray}

From the first condition, $x = -A^{T}\lambda/2$

Substitute into second to get $\lambda = -2(AA^{T})^{-1}y$

Hence $x=A^{T}(AA^{T})^{-1}y\equiv(A^{T}A)^{-1}A^{T}y$

MY QUESTION:

I want do the same derivation with Lagrange multipliers, but now I want consider complexs numbers. So that:

\begin{eqnarray}
     \text{Minimize }   & x^{H}:x \nonumber\\
     \text{Subject to } & Ax = y \nonumber
  \end{eqnarray}
where $H$ is the Hermitian.

[(:) Should be a Frobenius inner product?]

How can I do it?

Comment: A basic question that presents itself is: what do you mean by minimising a complex quantity?

Comment: The solution x is complex but $X^{H}X$ is real. I want minimizing the real value $X^{H}X$ .

Comment: So you should write that you want to minimize the real value $X^HX$

Comment: It is written MINIMIZE $\mathbf{X}^H: \mathbf{X}$

Comment: My point is you cannot  MINIMIZE a  COMPLEX QUANTITY

Comment: MAN WE MINIMIZE A COST FUNCTION ($\mathbf{x}^{H}\mathbf{x}$) **WHICH IS REAL!!** A CONJUGATE NUMBER TIMES THE NUMBER **IS REAL**!!! THE COMPLEX NUMBER/VECTOR $\mathbf{x}$ IS THE OPTIMAL SOLUTION FOR MINIMUM COST FUNCTION!

Comment: You have an error in your text. $x^H: x$ is NOT THE SAME as $x^Hx$. This is mathematics, not some social media outlet where you yell at people.

Comment: Is that why I put question mark here **[(:) Should be a Frobenius inner product?]**